# Sorting a 2D array by the [i][2] element

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Assume I have this 2D array:

```
array[0][] = {5,B,2}
array[1][] = {9,R,4}
array[2][] = {3,B,1}
array[3][] = {1,R,8}
```

How can I sort this array in such a way that this is the output:

```
array[0][] = {3,B,1}
array[1][] = {5,B,2}
array[2][] = {9,R,4}
array[3][] = {1,R,8}
```

Basically sorting them based on the [i][2] element.

This is how I declared the array:

```
String[][] splitnodes = new String[7][];
```

Is it even possible? If it is, how?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Not really, I don't know where to start it :/ @ControlAltDel

Comment: I am curious to know what type your array is? Could you please post the code that declared the `array` variable?

Comment: @jrook edited the question

Comment: If you actually try to compile and run the code you have posted, you will get a `Cannot resolve symbol B` error (among others). I suggest you start by declaring your array and other variables correctly. Sometimes it is better to just start typing code without worrying too much about an elegant solution or algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to implement a "normal search" like insertion sort, where you only compare the second element, and then carry the rest of the elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use any sorting tecnique and in the step involving the comparision you need to compare the 2nd element of each sub array.  Using the utility method provided in the J0DK you may also use `sort`method defined in `Arrays.java`.

```
java.util.Arrays.sort(array, new 
    java.util.Comparator<String[]> () {
        public int compare(String[] a, String[] b) {
             return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt( a[2]), Integer.parseInt(b[2]));
        }
});
```

Comment: @Andy Thomas I edited my answer